Girl Dies and Wakes up on an Autopsy Table in a Parallel Universe
From what I remember (read the book in 2017), the girl is from a family of witches and to awaken their power they have to die. Dying sends them to the parallel world, where everything is relatively the same except a few noticeable details. No one knows it’s a parallel world except the people who’ve been brought over from the original one. This is still fuzzy, so whether they call themselves witches isn’t quite fact.
The first scene I remember is from the beginning of the book. The protagonist dies and then wakes up on an autopsy table, she can’t move anything or speak. The man who’s supposed to be doing the autopsy is incredibly creepy and decides he wants to uh, violate her corpse. She starts panicking because she’s still frozen, but then she manages to sit up and scare him off before her body goes back to being unable to move.
After she gets saved, she can go between the original and parallel worlds. I think it’s triggered by sleeping. You can only move between worlds if you’re strong enough to survive the first time. If you’re not strong enough, you stay in the parallel world and the ‘you’ in the original stays dead.
The second scene is where she’s with her boyfriend, and they start reminiscing about a time they had sex. I think they were talking about the first time. They remember it differently, and they argue about who was right. She thinks they just got in the shower right away, he says he washed his hands first.
Somewhere along the line, a child comes into the picture. I’m not sure if they have a tail in the original world, but in the parallel one the tail is covered in venomous spikes. The child is also working with the villain in the parallel world.
The third scene is where she’s facing the villain, and the villain calls for the child to stab her with their tail. Instead of stabbing the protagonist, they stab the villain and I’m fairly certain she dies. It’s revealed that the child and her boyfriend had both killed themselves to help her in the parallel world. When she wakes up in the original world, her boyfriend’s beside her except he’s dead because he wasn’t strong enough. The child was fine though, so they’re alive in both worlds and the boyfriend is stuck in the parallel one.

This is basically identical to the last time you went looking; https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/13sj6jy/fantasy_book_about_a_girl_who_dies_and_goes_to_a/ Have you not recalled any additional details in the last year? Where else have you asked and what books have you ruled out?

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

For example, what was the heroine's name? What was the love-interest's name? Was there explicit sex? What was the target audience for the book? Did you read it in a paperback or online/kindle? What was the motivation of the villain? Did the villain attack her immediately? How did she defend herself? What language did you read this in? Did it have anything distinctive on the cover? Who was the author? Was the author male or female? What powers does dying awaken? Can she use these powers at will or is there a learning sequence?
